# how to check directory has worked or not after a defined date?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am very new to PowerShell so please be nice and explain/comment if you answer with a bunch of code.

My goal : make big clean-up & free space on a server

My way to do that : identify folders than nobody accessed *(even in read)*, after a specified date

currently I ran :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -filter *.log | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

as a first step.

I also tried to make list of directories like :

```
Get-Children -Directory -recurse | where-object { $_.lastaccesstime -lt ((get-date).adddays( variablename )) } | select fullname, lastaccesstime, lastwritetime
```

want to do something like :

```
while find directory
     read recurse sub-directories_properties_access_time
        if last_access < specified_date then delete all recurse
     next
done
```